# Kotlin, how can I switch from one fragment to another by clicking a button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have two fragments and I want to switch from one to the other by clicking the button, as simple as possible.

The Id of the button is 'fragmentOneButton' and I want to know how to make through the setOnClickListener on the button move to the next fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Use replace to change between fragments. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions)

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout_id, fragment)
```

Or this is also a way :

```
var fragment: Fragment? = null

        when (itemId) {
                    R.id.fragment_information -> {
                        fragment = ComplainFragment()
                    }
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout_id, fragment)
                transaction.commit()
        }
```